# MongoDB - Cannot find specific fields in embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm querying the documents and I just to get 2 specific fields, but for some reason the nested value is not returned.

```
    Watcher.find(query, { id: 1, 'address.current': 1 }).exec((err, result) => {
 if (err) {
   ////
 } else {
   res.status(200).json(result);
 }});
```

In this case I do not get any value for 'address.current'.
But when I set it like so, is returns the complete 'address' object.

```
Watcher.find(query, { id: 1, address: 1 }).exec((err, result) => {
   if (err) {
     ////
   } else {
     res.status(200).json(result);
   }
});
```

Document for example:

```
{
    "_id": "5a51080e939530fdc0c77f9a",
    "address": {
        "street": 10,
        "zip_code": null,
        "current": false
    }
}
```

The desired output is:

```
{
    "_id": "5a51080e939530fdc0c77f9a",
    "addres.current": false
    }
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: could you add an example of your document?

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: Working... https://mongoplayground.net/p/XS0NXXXCfpX

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, thank you, it works. Is there are way to get the result not as a object. Like so for example:  'address.current' instead of 'address: {current: }'

Comment: can you please update your question and show the output you want

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": query }},
  { "$project": {
    "addressCurrent": "$address.current"
  }}
])
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pMfGpBflCrA)